# web3.py getAmountOut() outputs INVALID LIQUIDITY

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I'm trying to use the getAmountOut() function from the Uniswap Router-02 which should tell you how much of output token you should receive for a given input token amount.

Problem is I am getting the following error:

`web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY`.

Now does this function require you to use some ETH because it has to pay gas fees in order to execute or is there an error in my code ?

```
def checkSubTrade(exchange, in_token_address, out_token_address, amount):

# Should be general cross exchange but would have to check if each routers contain the same methods
router_address = w3.toChecksumAddress(router_dict[str(exchange)])
router_abi = abi_dict[str(exchange)]
router_contract = w3.eth.contract(address = router_address, abi = router_abi)
swap_path = [in_token_address, out_token_address]

output = router_contract.functions.getAmountsOut(amount, swap_path).call()

return output

output = checkSubTrade('uniswap', token_dict['WETH'], token_dict['UNI'], 100000000)
print(output())
```

`token_dict`, `router_dict` contain the addresses and `abi_dict` contains the ABI for the DEX.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to check two things.

1. router_address : maybe it is different then you think
   when you go scope page that chain providing, you can see transaction
   detail. and there is from and to, for example this [link](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x63339ac75aff9ed13e67a2c8f5c741953d0dd97cf5516f9ab66c7d014e03af01) you
   might see the to, in swap session to is route_address. so like that, you need to search in scope page to get route_address
2. router_abi : i think you using uniswapv2library, but in uniswap2library there is many other abi. for example factoryabi. so you need to check abi is correct or not. i highly recommend that you need to get or make solidity file of abi and change abi via web ide

Comment: Ok I think it is a problem with the ABI, I have been following some tutorials and they were all following the same procedure. Thank you for your advice !